# Bad CPU type in executable mac Intel core

Tags: macos, homebrew, cpu-architecture, nvm

Trying to install a specific version of nvm

But I get

```
nvm install 16.14.2
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Bad CPU type in executable
A version number is required.
```

My mac has the `2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9`

```
file /opt/homebrew/bin/awk
/opt/homebrew/bin/awk: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

and

```
uname -a
Darwin <mystuff> 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: <timestamp>; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Don't know what to do to get this to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Means what it says -- you have the arm64 version of awk installed, but an amd64/x86_64 CPU. There's no getting that executable to work on your CPU -- you need to install a version compiled for your architecture.

Comment: Okay, so I've installed gwak through homebrew and that hasn't fixed anything. How do I get the version that I need? And of what? Awk or gwak? I understand the issue but I don't know HOW to fix it.

Comment: Recently came across information that macOS uses NAWK, not GAWK, to run awk. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations
Link to the github repo: https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk

Comment: Tried: `brew install awk`, but got ->
`Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!`

Comment: Found out that my ARM default prefix is wrong:
- `/usr/local` on macOS intel
- `/opt/homebrew` on macOS ARM
- /`home/linuxbrew` on Linux

------ In order to fix it I had to uninstall Homebrew, found here: https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew

And then I had to then reinstall it, found at same link. Reinstalling it changed the default prefix from the incorrect `/opt/homebrew` to the correct `/usr/local` prefix

Comment: Consider adding an answer with the same content as the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that my ARM default prefix is wrong: - `/usr/local` on macOS intel - `/opt/homebrew` on macOS ARM - `/home/linuxbrew` on Linux ------ In order to fix it I had to uninstall Homebrew, found here: [github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) And then I had to then reinstall it, found at same link. Reinstalling it changed the default prefix from the incorrect `/opt/homebrew` to the correct `/usr/local` prefix