# Mac Intel: zsh: bad CPU type in executable: rustup

Tags: macos, cpu-architecture, apple-m1, rustup

I had a Mac with an M1 chip which I backed up on an external HDD. I used the backup to setup a Mac with an Intel chip. When I try to rust `rustup` I get the following:

```
$ rustup
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: rustup
```

I have tried using the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72006530/bad-cpu-type-in-executable-mac-intel-core) answer to no avail.

For reference:

```
$ cat /Users/user/.cargo/config
[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

Any suggestions on how to get rust up and running would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Intel isn't / doesn't support aarch64. Delete all binaries compiled for ARM, and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Charles Duffy's suggestion I did the following:

```
# Go to generated binaries
cd /Users/<username>/.cargo/bin
# Remove all of them
rm *
# Get a fresh rustup
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh\n
# Add Mac Intel to target
rustup target add x86_64-apple-darwin
# Add Mac Intel to toolchain
rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
# Set Mac Intel toolchain as default
rustup default stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
# Run rustup update for good measure
rustup update
```

Hope this helps!